# Is it right to say 'You are friends'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, grammaticality

If I want to say to a group of people that they are each other's friends, can I say:

> **You're friends.**

or should absolutely say:

> You're **each other's** friends

Comment: One common related phrase to know is "We're all friends here." which you would use if you're trying to make a group of people comfortable (for instance, to share information with everyone in the room).  You would use it if you're trying to remind everyone that it's not necessary to act defensively or worry that anyone (including the speaker) is trying to harm anyone else present.

Comment: I just want to know if "You're friends" is **GRAMMATICALLY** right or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your point, the answer is **Yes**

> In standard English, *you* is **both singular and plural**; it always takes a verb form that originally marked the word as plural, (i.e. you are, in common with we are and they are).

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You)

That means while using "**You**", you are already referring to the group of people, and thus making the "*friends*" or other adjective/adverb/clauses/etc. pointing to all subjects of "**You**".

Answer (score 0):

> *You're* friends. (meaning: *You are* friends.)

is fine. But when spoken this might be misunderstood as:

> *Your* friends

which has a different meaning. I would use one of these:

> You are friends.
>   You are each other's friends.
>   You are friends with each other.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid confusing "your" and "you're," it's important to really pronounce the 
"**you**" in "**you**'re." "Your" sounds more like [yoh-r] in American English.

In addition to what user3169 said, you could also say:

> You're all friends.

or

> You all are friends.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is grammatically correct, however the context is important.

Usually when speaking about a small group of people (say 4 or less), one would could say

> **you're friends**
>   Why were you fighting with him? **You're friends**, aren't you?
>
> The three boys are **friends** *of each other*

When speaking to or about a **group** of people, one would usually say

> **you're all friends**
>   Settle down team, no need to argue, **we're all friends** here.
>
> The team are **all friends** *of each other*

"**You're friends**" can also work with groups, but **all** usually gets added to emphasize the whole.

"**Each other**" is implied when speaking about friendship between people, it can be used for emphasis or if there is ambiguity between whether the friendship is between two people, or between the two people and a third person.